# in Web Service theres a error" There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Guid. The value '1' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'."

Tags: c#, json, winforms, web-services

Im trying to test a webservice and it apears an error like this "There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Guid. The value '1' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'." when i do this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrotN.png)

Comment: What input to you give it? Post code and error messages as text.

Comment: I don't know c# and you didn't post the relevant code, but it looks like you are passing a value that does not comply with the GUID type that your code is expecting.  You are passing '1' which certainly doesn't comply with the GUID RFC.  Hope this helps

Comment: the input i gave it was "1" but independently of what i put it always gives me the same error and the error message was "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
  Message=The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:ID. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Guid. The value '1' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'. " @madreflection

Comment: Well, "1" is not a GUID so your input is invalid. This error message is entirely expected. Give it a GUID instead.

Comment: ive been trying to understand what a guid is but the method thats this code calls is this "[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/IReferenciasWS/ObterTodosPontosEntrega", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]

Comment: *continuation* 
        public PontoEntregaBE ObterTodosPontosEntrega(string ID) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("ObterTodosPontosEntrega", new object[] {
                        ID});
            return ((PontoEntregaBE)(results[0]));
        }

Comment: A quick Google search of "GUID" gives plenty of information. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: thank you for the advice but one more thing why is it asking me a guid in the first place im new to c# and i got tasked with doing this i dont really know what im doing

Comment: If you want to know why a web service requires a particular type for a particular input, I suggest you ask whoever wrote the web service or whoever tasked you with doing this..

Comment: pratically im using a web service and im calling a method in that web service for example if i input the id it should return a value but i dont understand c# or web services so its kinda difficut  and ive searched and they start talking about json

Comment: It's simple: the service you're calling expects a GUID. Based on what you've said, you were given a task that's beyond your capability at this time. You should be seeking not just help on this task, but also *mentorship* for your career in general, from within the company. Stack Overflow is not the place for what you need right now.

Comment: yeah you are right but im a intern and i got here and they basicaly said here take this web service see if it works good luck i have no clue who did this and im pretty sure it was made back in 2012

Comment: *"but im a intern"* - so? Even if you're unpaid, they can't expect to get you complete a task if the task is beyond your [zone of proximal development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_of_proximal_development). It's in their best interest to bring you to the point where you can be productive, unless this is a throw-away task and they don't really care if you complete it.

Comment: yah ill talk to the boss about it i dont even know if he even knows how to do it himself we´ll se thanks for the help really aprecciated.